# Disable IE9 Javascript debugger when using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-9

Is there a way to disable javascript debugging when using Visual Studio with IE9?

Comment: Disable the IE9 debugger so that the debugger defers to visual studio?

Comment: @Quintin Robinson, I would like do not use any javascript debugger at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click the `Tools (Alt+X)` button, then click the `Internet Options` menu item.

In the `Advanced` Tab, and in the `Browsing` category:

Check `Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)`

This should disable the Javascript debugger

Comment: thanks for your help, but this option already is checked see http://img143.imageshack.us/i/imagemier.png/

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of what appears when javascript encounters an error?

Comment: Did you change the Javascript debugging option recently? If so
Have you tried restarting Internet Explorer & Visual Studio? (This may include shutting down sidebar.exe on windows) Infact it may be better to log on and off.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  On Windows 7 32 bit, Visual Studio 2010 and IE are ignoring the disable script debugging box which has always been checked.

Comment: Have you tried closing all of those applications (and potentially logging off and on) after changing these options?

Comment: This won't disable debugging when launched from Visual Studio as Visual Studio is enabling debugging for the instance of IE it's launched. The answer from Andras below has a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the solution provided by Dotmister, but it didn't work on my Vista (x64), VS2010 and IE9.

However I tried the following and it worked (source: http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2011/02/disable-stopjavascript-debugging-in-visual-studio/)

1. Open the application Property page and select the Web tab
2. Select “Start External Program” and set the path to iexplorer.exe
3. Enter the URL in the Command line argument option
4. Hit F5 to commence debugging.

My debugger was very slow when I hit a breakpoint, partly because I had the Edit and Continue enabled (you can disable it in VS under Tools -> Options -> Debuggins -> Edit and Continue) and partly because I could not disable JavaScript debugging.

Now it is significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable *all* script debugging in VS via:
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639} /f

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the web application and choose Properties Click Web tab
2. on the left and choose “Don’t open page” radio button on the left
3. panel Start Debugging (press F5)
4. Open Internet Explorer and navigate the URL. { I just pinned that instance of IE to my taskbar ;-) }

Answer (score 0):

If the disable checkboxes in IE doesn't work for youm then in VS go to

Tools > Options > Debugging > Just-In-Time > Uncheck  Script Option.

This worked for me.