# Webbrowser - get rid from error window

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

Webbrowser component is hosted in my winForm application. On one site occurred JS error and webbrowser show me error window. "Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference" 
The same error occurred in installed IE, I have seen it in debug mode, but IE doesn't show this error window. I need to hide this window in my application too.

I can't set **scriptErrorSuppressed = true** because in this case window for select certificate is not opened too, and I can't open site page at all.

What I have tried:

1. *document.Window.Error += new HtmlElementErrorEventHandler(Window_Error);* - event is not fired at all
2. *IOleCommandTarget::Exec* - it occurs after error window was closed, and doesn't take affect to this window

Is there any way to get rid from this window?

[image: error window]

Translation:

Webpage error Do you want to debug this webpage? This page contain errors that that might prevent it from displaying or working correctly. If this page has not been verified, press No. "Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: Could you translate your exception message to english?

Comment: Of course, sorry:
Webpage error
Do you want to debug this webpage?
This page contain errors that that might prevent it from displaying or working correctly. If this page has not been verified, press No.
 "Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eliminated this window by setting "Disable Script Debugger" to "yes" in registry HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

Answer (score 0):

If somebody uses VisualStudio and found this question, also see

- [Disable IE9 Javascript debugger when using Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381334/disable-ie9-javascript-debugger-when-using-visual-studio-2010)
- [How to disable script debugging in Visual Studio 2010 when running Asp.Net website project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512225/how-to-disable-script-debugging-in-visual-studio-2010-when-running-asp-net-websi)

Debug->Options & Settings and select Just-In-Time and Uncheck Script